# Only the first IF condition works, and the rest doesn't when nested in Process Builder formula

Tags: formula, process-builder, regular-expressions, conditional, nested

**GOAL**: I'm trying to create this criteria in Process Builder where I can detect phone number like (000) 000-0000, 000-000-0000 and 000.000.0000 and turn them into +1 0000000000 format.

I tried to write the formula like below and if I input (000) 000-0000 into HomePhone field, that turns into +1 000000000 successfully, but if I tried to update data with 000-000-0000, it would stay 000-000-0000. The same for period format, it stays as 000.000.0000. When I tried those two nested conditions one at a time instead of nesting inside of IF statement, each condition works fine.

Please help me fix the IF statement so that nested conditions get hit when regex returns true.

```
IF(
REGEX([Contact].HomePhone, "\\D*?(\\d\\D*?){10}"), SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([Contact].HomePhone, "(", "+1 "), ") ", ""), "-", ""),
IF(
REGEX([Contact].HomePhone, "^([0-9]{1,3})(?:[0-9\\-]?){4,16}"),
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("+1 " & [Contact].HomePhone, "-", ""), "-", ""),
IF(
REGEX([Contact].HomePhone, "^([0-9]{1,3})(?:[0-9\\.]?){4,16}"),
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("+1 " & [Contact].HomePhone, ".", ""), ".", ""),
[Contact].HomePhone)))
```

******UPDATES******
Changing my first regex to much more narrowed down test like this `REGEX([Contact].HomePhone, "^\\([0-9]{1,3}\\)(?:[0-9\\-]?){4,16}")`helped. Thank you Mr David Reed for your help below!

*****Another Solution*****
This solution was from the Salesforce Trailblazer Community. fyi
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000a3hMQAQ

```
IF (NOT(BEGINS([Contact].HomePhone, "+")),
"+1"& SUBSTITUTE(
      SUBSTITUTE(
      SUBSTITUTE(
      SUBSTITUTE([Contact].HomePhone,'-', ''),'(', ''), '), ' ', ''),'.', ''),
        [Contact].HomePhone)
```

Comment: Reminder that the syntax is `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've seen people nest IF statement and use it as IFs nested inside of else statement. Could you elaborate on what you mean by your comment? Thanks!

Comment: in my experience, try vastly simplifying the nested IFs to get something working, then add back in complexity until it breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex is overly broad and matches input that you didn't intend to match, resulting in (a) the `SUBSTITUTE()` functions not doing what you expect and (b) the further layers of `IF()` statements not being evaluated.

The regex `"\\D*?(\\d\\D*?){10}"` (or `\D*?(\d\D*?){10}`) also matches `000-000-0000` and `000.000.0000`, but `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([Contact].HomePhone, "(", "+1 "), ") ", ""), "-", "")` doesn't work for those formats (since the later arms of this logic are intended to handle those formats).

Consider refining your first regex to specifically match the phone number formats you're handling there by explicitly matching parentheses and dashes. You'll need to escape parentheses if you wish to match them in your regex. Alternately, consider inverting your logic to match the most specific regex first.

Comment: Awesome! After changing my first regex be more specific, it worked! Thank you so much for your help and great answer!